ASP.NET Core 8 Web API does not return XML
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API.
This is my Program.cs file:
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

This is the City class:
public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

And this is my controller which has a method for returning both JSON and XML results:
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[FormatFilter]
public class SampleController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{id:long}.{format?}")]
    public ActionResult<City> GetById(long id)
    {
        var result = CityInfo_DataStorage.InMemoryStorage
                                         .Cities
                                         .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);

        return Ok(result);
    }
}

The problem
The GetById method only returns JSON and when I try to get XML I get this error:

Error: response status is 406

I tried to call GetById method like this:
This URL works:
https://localhost:44347/api/Sample/1.json

This URL does not work and shows the error:
https://localhost:44347/api/Sample/1.xml

Can anybody help?
Thanks

Have you tried making GET https://localhost:44347/api/Sample/1 requests and setting the desired Accept header to tell the API what you want back? Accept=application/json for JSON, Accept=application/xml for XML

@marc_s Hello yes I did it but still it shows me Error!

Your codes working well on my side, https://i.sstatic.net/ainDR.png, what's the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson version you have used? Do you use the 8.0.3? How about try the  builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
// Add XML Data Formatter
options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
}).AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
}).AddXmlSerializerFormatters(); ?

@BrandoZhang Hi, I changed my code like what you said but it didn't work. maybe it is because of .Net 8?

I also used the same one , as you see ,it works well on my side. How you send the request in Postman or else? Check your postman settings, and make sure the accept is right like this  https://i.sstatic.net/A0A75.png

Try adding this attribute to your controller:
[Produces("application/json", "application/xml")]


I tried but it didn't work. I do not know the reason....
